# Sampling variance when the largest observation is removed

Tags: variance, sampling

I have the sampling variance of the sample mean: $V_1=\frac{1}{N-1}\sum_i (x_i-\bar{x})^2$. Now if the largest observation is removed, I have a new variance, $$V_2=\frac{1}{N-2}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (x_i-\bar{\bar{x}})^2$$ where $\bar{\bar{x}}$ is the new (reduced) mean of the $N-2$ observations.

Depending on the data, I could see $V_1$ could be greater or lesser than $V_2$. 
An intuitive example of $V_1>V_2$ is when you consider one anomalous large value and mostly small observations.

Is there an intuitively clear example where I can visually understand the case where $V_1<V_2$?

Comment: For a simple example let $x=(2,20,20)$.

Comment: @whuber: I was teaching some MBA kids there. I was able to give a numerical example, but they wanted something visually understandable, like what they get for $V_1>V_2$...

Comment: So, more generally, it sounds like you are seeking a way to *visualize* variance (and changes thereof).  Please indicate that in your question so you get appropriate answers.

Comment: When you say "largest sample" do you mean 'largest observation'? In statistics a [sample](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_%28statistics%29) is a collection of observations. Your largest observation is a member of your sample.

Answer (score 2):

Consider ${\bf x}=(1,8,9,10)$: $\bar x = 7$, $s^2 = 16 \frac23$. When you remove the highest value $x_4=10$, it only increases the influence of the low outlier $x_1=1$: $\bar x =6$, $s^2 = 19$. Feel free to play with numbers more to get all the results in integers :).